# hasura.io - connect postgres database - what is the correct database URL?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, hasura

Currently I am trying to create a GraphQL API and I would like to connect to a already running postgreSQL database.
I was looking for the connection settings in pgadmin and found the following:
Hostname: localhost
Port: 5432
Username: postgres
Password: postgres
Database: SuperMart_DB

I tried to connect and inserted the following Database URLs in hasura:

```
postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/SuperMart_DB
postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/SuperMart_DB
```

Also tried out different combinations of `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` in the URLs upon but nothing worked.

I get this error:

```
Inconsistent object: connection error
```

Could you tell me what I should try to do?

When I do it with python it is working and I can query the database:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port = 5432, database="SuperMart_DB", user="postgres", password="postgres")
```

Comment: Where & how are you running your hasura server? It's likely that your Hasura lives in another network, so 127.0.0.1 goes to hasura, not your local.

Comment: OK, thank you! It is running in cloud.hasura.io.

Comment: Hasura cloud cannot talk to your local network except if you're using a tool like ngrok or localtunnel.
This tool will give you an URL you can copy/past in the hasura cloud to make it work.

This is a very temporary solution though. Hasura cloud isn't meant to reach your local db, but a db deployed somewhere else and publicly accessible (like in AWS)